# Closing a ApplicationWindow and open a new one?

Tags: c++, qml

I'm facing this problem while trying to switch from a ApplicationWindow to another.

I have this first Window called login.qml which opens the main.qml through the following signal:

```
onIdAutenticadoChanged: {
    if(idAutenticado > 0){
        console.log("login.qml: Autenticado ID: " + idAutenticado);
        LoginController.abrirMain();
        close();
    } else if(idAutenticado == 0){
        senhaInput.text = "";
        console.log("Falha na autenticação: Usuário e/ou senha inválidos.");
        lblMsgErro.text = "Usuário e/ou senha inválidos.";
        lblMsgErro.visible = true;
        loginInput.focus = true;
    }
}
```

The slot **LoginController.abrirMain()** will load and show the main.qml

```
void QLoginController::abrirMain()
{
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("MainController", new QMainController(0,m_autenticado));
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().at(0));
    window->showFullScreen();
}
```

**The problem is:** main.qml is not being shown.

```
//main.qml
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    modality: "WindowModal"
    visibility: "FullScreen"
    color: "#09435b"
}
```

**Question:** Am I using the right approach to open this new window? If not, how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you create the engine on stack :), which will be deleted automatically before `abrirMain()` returns and hence destroying the window too.

You should create engine on heap. Something like this:

```
// 'this' will become engine's parent and will automaticlaly delete engine when 'this' is deleted
QQmlApplicationEngine *engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine(this); 
engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("MainController", new QMainController(0,m_autenticado));
engine->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine->rootObjects().at(0));
window->showFullScreen();
```